# SwiftUI ZIndex Animation is Not Taking Place

Tags: swiftui

I have the following code:

```
 @State private var couponId: Int = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ScrollView {
            
            VStack(spacing: -50) {
                
                ForEach(1...20, id: \.self) { index in
                    CouponCell()
                        .zIndex(couponId == index ? 2 : 0)
                       .animation(.spring())
                        .onTapGesture {
                            withAnimation {
                                couponId = index
                            }
                        }
                }
            }
            
            .padding().frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
```

The the user selects a particular CouponCell then I update the Zindex so it appears on top of other cells. This works but it does not animate at all. What am I missing and why animation is not taking place.

I am using Xcode 12 Beta 2 on macOS Big Sur Beta 2

Answer (score 2):

The `.zIndex` itself is not animatable modifier, because actually nothing to animate in view z position - it is either below or above.

Probably you meant (or would prefer) something combined like the following

Tested on replicated code (Xcode 12)

[image: demo]

```
CouponCell()
    .zIndex(couponId == index ? 2 : 0)
    .scaleEffect(couponId == index ? 1.02 : 1)
    .animation(.spring(), value: couponId)
    .onTapGesture {
        couponId = index
    }
```